# Open2/Open3.pm perl issue when attempting to execute perl script on Windows 10

Tags: perl, oracle11g, windows-10

Im trying to execute a perl script which updates values in a remote database. This perl script executes fine on Windows 7 but fails on Windows 10.
The perl exe which is calling the script has been included with the installation of Oracle 11g 64 bit.
The specific error which is raised on Windows 10 is as follows:

**open2: Can't call method "close" on an undefined value at C:/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_64/perl/lib/IPC/Open3.pm line 365.**

Extract of script below:

```
open2 ($RPIPE, $WPIPE, 'sqlplus -s /nolog') or die "\n";

unless ($pid = fork()) {
    print $WPIPE "set hea off\n\n";
    print $WPIPE "conn sys\/".$psys_pass."\@".$pdbname." as sysdba\n\n";
    print $WPIPE "from dba_users\n";
    print $WPIPE "where username in \(select grantee from dba_role_privs where granted_role=\'COMPONENT_OWNER\' and admin_option=\'NO\'\)\;\n";
    print $WPIPE "exit\n";
    close $WPIPE;
    exit 0;
}

close $WPIPE;
@pdbcmds=();
while(<$RPIPE>) { if    ($_ =~ /^alter user/ ) { push (@pdbcmds, $_); }
        }
close $RPIPE;
waitpid ($pid,0);
```

Comment: Well, it would be good if we could see the script, but seems like you are trying to close something that is not defined...

Comment: Ive added the rest of the script now

Comment: Ok, again, you are doing `close $WPIPE;` in the loop, then again after the loop, makes sense? So the script is complaining about the `close` command outside the loop, because you already closed it inside the loop. Remove `close $WPIPE;` inside the loop, before `exit 0;`

Comment: You shouldn't be using IPC::Open2/3. They're too low level. For starters, it's too easy to write code that's subject to deadlocks. For example, your code is an example of such buggy code. IPC::Run is a much better module.